# Cannot see TFS changeset history

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

I ma using TFS 2015 on Visual Studio 2010 with SP1.  I was able to do check-ins and outs at the beginning and viewed the changeset history and then I copied the files to a different location and then suddenly I can't see FURTHER histories any more even though I can still doing my normal check-ins/outs.  Not sure what happened...

I have tried the following:

- Got the project afresh from TFS into another directories on my PC
- Deleteed TFS cache
- Reinstalled VS2010 and SP1

My other colleagues do not have this problem. Can anyone suggest what I can do?  Thanks.
WM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also,
before remaping remove the below cache:
%localappdata%\Microsoft\Team Foundation\5.0\Cache
SO the complete steps will be :
1 - unmapped all project

2 - [Remove workspace][1][1]: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms245474(v=vs.100).aspx

3 - delete the cache folder @: %localappdata%\Microsoft\Team Foundation\5.0\Cache

4 - remap project and Get Latest Version

Comment: It works perfect. It's been bugging me for a while.  Thanks heaps.

Answer (score 0):

Try that :

1 - unmapped all project

2 - [Remove workspace][1][1]: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms245474(v=vs.100).aspx

3 - remap project and Get Latest Version